# Yii2 Saving tabular data using yii2-formwizard

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-formwizard

I am integrating [yii2-formwizard](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard) for tabular input but unable to submit the data to my controller action and use `Model::loadMultiple`.

I have to declare my model as array and then I need to initialize it before passing to view and in `buttflattery/yii2-formwizard` front-end I must specify my model as array fine but I can not retrieve data from my controller dynamically.

I need to dynamically create instance from front-end and save them in back end.
I can save only the instance I have initialize from my controller.if I do not initialize only first one instance saved.and also when I initialize multiple instance using for loop, front end replicate for all instance at once which again I do not need.

```
//controller
public function actionCreatemulti()
    {
        $this->layout='layout2';

        $education = [new Edusubject()];
            //## initialize array for 2 element (if I not initialize only one object pass or saved)
           for ($i=0; $i < 2 ; $i++) { 
             $education[]= new Edusubject();
        }

        //## Model::loadMultiple --> works only if $education is declared as array
        if (Model::loadMultiple($education, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($education)) {
            foreach ($education as $edu) {
                $edu->save(false);
            }
            return $this->render('dummy');
        }

        return $this->render('createmulti', [
            'education' => $education,    
        ]);
}
```

FormWizard code in my View

```
    <?php

    echo FormWizard::widget(
        [
            'formOptions' => [
                'id' => 'my_form_tabular'
            ],
            'steps' => [
                [
                //should be a single model or array of Activerecord model objects but for a single model only see wiki on github
                    'model' => $education, //## here I canot declared array again as I pass an array alredy from controller

                //set step type to tabular
                    'type' => FormWizard::STEP_TYPE_TABULAR,
```

when i declare model as array in my view i can get dynamic form as described in [wiki](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard/wiki/Tabular-Steps-(New-Feature)) but I can not save this array since I can not implement yii2 Collecting tabular input as described, on the other hand if I declare model as array and initialize it and send to front end then form is not dynamic. it is shown all instance in form so I need not press "add" button, which I do not need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I developed this widget but before i suggest you anything you should read about the basic implementation of the tabular inputs although the guide is'nt completely helpful there are portions that are still under **`TBD`** and code sample for inserting/creating tabular data into the table isnt added yet with that much detail, but it is always better to look into the source method, after all we are Engineers and we should be able to understand the implementation of any function either a part of framework core or of a separate file.

### Addressing Problems

Now about the issue, you have no reason to use the for loop that you have added on top of your action

```
 for ($i=0; $i < 2 ; $i++) { 
     $education[]= new Edusubject();
 }
```

You took that part from the guide [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-tabular-input) and copy-pasted it as is in your code **¯\_(ツ)_/¯** .

This part of code in the guide is for the understanding only how the tabular models array should be populated and then provided for loading and validating while **creating new records**.

### Understanding

We need to load and validate the tabular inputs via

- [`Model::loadMultiple($models,$attributes)`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#loadMultiple()-detail)
- [`Model::validateMultiple($models)`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#validateMultiple()-detail)

Both of them take `$models`array as 1st parameter which should hold the instances of the models to be loaded/validated.

For `loadMultiple($models, $attributes)` remember that it will load all the attributes specified in the `$attributes` array into each of the models specified in the `$models` array, **and all of those models need to be of the same class**. the `$attributes` array can be one of `$_POST` or `$_GET` or any other valid array, see the docs for details.

For `validateMultiple($models)` it can be different models or same, it will call `validate()` on each model in the `$models` array.

### Implementation

So you need to change it to below

```
public function actionCreatemulti()
    {
        $this->layout='layout2';

        $education = [new Edusubject()];

        //cehck if post request
        if(Yii::$app->request->isPost){
            //get total models submitted
            $count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('Edusubject',[]));

            //start the loop from 1 rather than 0 and use the $count for limit
            for ($i=1; $i < $count ; $i++) { 
               $education[]= new Edusubject();
            }

            if (
                 Model::loadMultiple($education, Yii::$app->request->post()) 
                 && Model::validateMultiple($education)
            ) {
                foreach ($education as $edu) {
                    $edu->save(false);
                }
                return $this->render('dummy');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('createmulti', [
            'education' => $education,    
        ]);
}
```

and in your view the `model` property in the `FormWizard` will look like below

```
'model' => $education,
```

I just tested it on localhost and it loads, validates and saves correctly.

Comment: I hoped you have not get my issue. I have used as you explained here.but I can only save (capture) only the first element of form model.(always saved one element regardless the number of element in form.)

Comment: @noc_kockout ahh, sorry I just got what you are saying, I overlooked it, I have updated the answer please see the latest code it should save all the models submitted from the form now

Comment: @noc_kockout good to hear it works for you now, do mark the answer as accepted/correct by clicking the green mark, so others having the same problem can also benefit the solution