# Yii2 Using Select2 with tabular step of yii2-formwizard

Tags: javascript, yii2, kartik-v, yii2-formwizard

I am using [yii2-formwizard](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard) which is a handy tool in my project with `kartik\select2`. Everything is work perfectly except when I press add to get next group `select2` drop-down on previous groups are disappeared.

This has happen when I modify my controller to capture data from my model as explained in my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57713074/yii2-saving-tabular-data-using-buttflattery-yii2-formwizard), I have missed something in scripting side I'm bit poor in jquery/JS etc, anyhow except that data is being saved and widget work perfectly

### my controller

```
<?php

public function actionCreatemulti()
{
    $this->layout = 'layout2';
    $model = [new Todelete()];
    $sex = [['id' => 1, 'name' => 'male'], ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'female']];

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {

        $count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('Todelete', []));
        //start the loop from 1 rather than 0 and use the $count for limit
        for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $model[] = new Todelete();
        }

        if (Model::loadMultiple($model, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($model)) {
            foreach ($model as $md) {
                $md->save(false);
            }
            return $this->render('index');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'sex' => $sex
    ]);
}
```

### my view

```
echo FormWizard::widget(
    [
        'formOptions' => [
            'id' => 'my_form_tabular'
        ],
        'steps' => [
            [
                //should be a single model or array of Activerecord model objects but for a single model only see wiki on github
                'model' => $model,

                //set step type to tabular
                'type' => FormWizard::STEP_TYPE_TABULAR,

                'fieldConfig' => [
                    'sex' => [
                        'widget' => Select2::class,
                        'containerOptions' => [
                            'class' => 'form-group'
                        ],
                        'options' => [
                            'data' => $data,
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control'
                            ],
                            'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true,
                                'placeholder' => 'Select sex'
                            ]
                        ],

                        //set tabular events for select2 fix which doesnot work correctly after cloning

                        'tabularEvents' => [

                            'beforeClone' => "function(event, params){
                                //fix for select2 destroy the plugin

                                let element = $(this);
                                element.select2('destroy');
                            }",
                            "afterClone" => "function(event, params){

                                //bind select2 again after clone

                                let element = $(this);
                                let elementId = $(this).attr('id');
                                let dataKrajee = eval(element.data('krajee-select2'));
                                let dataSelect2Options = element.data('s2-options');
                                $.when(element.select2(dataKrajee)).done(initS2Loading(elementId, dataSelect2Options));
                            }",
                            "afterInsert" => "function(event,params){
                                //initialize the options for the select2 after initializing
//changed according to my environment

                                let selectElement = $(this).find('.field-todelete-'+params.rowIndex+'-sex > select');
                                let dataKrajee = eval(selectElement.data('krajee-select2'));
                                selectElement.select2(dataKrajee);
                            }"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]

        ]
    ]
);
```

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/31/158dc0f338e0d780747c5f72fa2ed6bb-full.png https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/31/4e394e87aa162d3f457c32af8d30373b-full.png

Comment: the images you added at the end of your question arent opening and about the select2 you have a working demo [here](https://yii2plugins.omaraslam.com/formwizard/tabular-step) which uses the select2 within the tabular steps to show the working, and the detailed docs are on [GITHUB-WIKI](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard/wiki/Tabular-Steps:-Working-with-3rd-Party-Widgets) you must be missing some class name do you have a live link to the application ? also please look into the console for javascript errors when you press the add button

Comment: tahnks for your help,I update links & gone through all above mentioned link.i don't get any error in console.

Comment: added an answer for you , and please dont add un-necesary slashes in the question it kills the readability i have rolled-back and edited your question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason

The issue you have pointed out **does** exist, and you are right about it. But this issue is related with the recent change to the `kartik\select2 @V2.1.4`.The demo links are using an older version of the select2 `V2.1.3` which dont have this `dataset` attribute defined, and hence works correctly.

The widget does not integrate all these changes and leaves on the user who is integrating the widget

> The reason is that it won't be possible to control it correctly inside
>   the plugin as there could be any widget a user wants to use and going
>   to keep adding the code for every other widget isn't what I would vote
>   for. So a better approach would be to provide the event triggers for
>   the specific actions which require a pre or post-processing of an
>   element, where according to the needs the user can adjust his code

### Troubleshooting

Now about the issue, there is a new dataset attribute **`data-select2-id`** which holds the name of the input that the select2 is bind to and after cloning the new element that attribute is not updated to the newer element id which is causing your old select element to vanish.

See the image below it is from my own code so just ignore the `address-0-city` field name as it is not related to your code and is for understanding only

[image]

### Solution

So we need to change the code in the `afterInsert` event to the below one

```
let selectElement = $(this).find('.field-todelete-'+params.rowIndex+'-sex > select');
let dataKrajee = eval(selectElement.data('krajee-select2'));

//update the dataset attribute to the
if (typeof selectElement[0].dataset.select2Id !== 'undefined') {

    //get the old dataset which has the old id of the input the select2 is bind to 
    let oldDataSelect2Id = selectElement[0].dataset.select2Id;

    //delete the old dataset
    delete selectElement[0].dataset.select2Id;

    //add the new dataselect pointing to the new id of the cloned element
    let newDataSelect2Id = oldDataSelect2Id.replace(
    /\-([\d]+)\-/,
    '-' + parseInt(params.rowIndex) + '-'
    );

    //add the new dataset with the new cloned input id 
    selectElement[0].dataset.select2Id= newDataSelect2Id;
}
selectElement.select2(dataKrajee);
```

**I will update the code on the wiki docs and the code samples along with the demos too in next few days.**

Hope it helps you out.

Comment: excellent explanation and it's work perfectly.as you explained I updated kartik/select2 and all widgets through composer this should the caused even I couldn't identified clearly.Again this widget is really useful than other similar implementation as it's super simple and very cleared for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when there is a collision of ids using widgets.
Check by inspecting the HTML page that this does not happen.
In particular, dwell on these sections (this code is only an example):

```
<Block1>
  <select id = "todelete-0-sex">
</Block1>
<Block2>
  <select id = "todelete-1-sex">
</Block2>

<Script>
  // ...
  $("# Todelete-0-sex").select2({...});
  // ...
  $("#Todelete-1-sex").select2({...});
  // ...
</Script>
```

I have replicated your code on a clean installation of Yii2 (2.0.25), using the two components:

- buttflattery/yii2-formwizard (1.4.6)
- kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 (v2.1.3)

with some minor changes not relevant to make the code work and everything seems ok.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoyUw.png)

**Recap**

1. verify that there are no conflicts when creating the two
   widgets
2. Check the version of the "yii2-formwizard" and "yii2-widget-select2" components

---

**MyController.php (controller)**

```
...
    public function actionTest()
    {
        //$this->layout = 'layout2';
        $model = [new Todelete(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'a', 'sex' => 'male']), new Todelete(['id' => 2, 'name' => 'b', 'sex' => 'male']), new Todelete(['id' => 3, 'name' => 'c', 'sex' => 'female'])];
        $sex = [['id' => 1, 'name' => 'male'], ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'female']];

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {

            $count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('Todelete', []));
            //start the loop from 1 rather than 0 and use the $count for limit
            for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $model[] = new Todelete();
            }

            if (Model::loadMultiple($model, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($model)) {
                foreach ($model as $md) {
                    $md->save(false);
                }
                return $this->render('index');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('test', [
            'model' => $model,
            'sex' => $sex
        ]);
    }
...
```

**Todelete.php (model)**

```
...
use yii\base\Model; // NOTE: in your case your model will most likely extend ActiveRecord instead of Model class

class Todelete extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $sex;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['id', 'integer'],
            [['sex', 'name'], 'string'],
        ];
    }
}
...
```

**create.php (view)**

```
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use \buttflattery\formwizard\FormWizard;

echo FormWizard::widget(
    [
        'formOptions' => [
            'id' => 'my_form_tabular'
        ],
        'steps' => [
            [
                //should be a single model or array of Activerecord model objects but for a single model only see wiki on github
                'model' => $model,

                //set step type to tabular
                'type' => FormWizard::STEP_TYPE_TABULAR,

                'fieldConfig' => [
                    'sex' => [
                        'widget' => Select2::class,
                        'containerOptions' => [
                            'class' => 'form-group'
                        ],
                        'options' => [
                            //'data' => $data,
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control'
                            ],
                            'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true,
                                'placeholder' => 'Select sex'
                            ]
                        ],

                        //set tabular events for select2 fix which doesnot work correctly after cloning

                    ]
                ]
            ]

        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with what you are talking about the inputs are cloned and the widget provides you the eents to destroy the select2 and then bind again, the above issue is realted to `data-select2-id` attribute that was added in the `v2.1.4`

Comment: It is correct what you say, however data-select2-id depends on the id of the select element. The kartik widget is just a wrapper around the select2 widget

Comment: its a tabular step that dynamically generates the inputs , you cant provide the `id` of the inputs yourself it just takes the first input id and adds increment to the current index like `todelete-0-sex` will be converted to `todelete-1-sex` and it is done by the widget script itself when cloning the select or any other inputs

Comment: and the `id` of the input in the `data-select2-id` needs to be updated for the element in the `afterInsert` event, i am saying all this because i developed this widget and that is how it works

Comment: ya I updated to newest kartik/select2 widget even I couldn't noticed, that's the root course for this issue.thanks for helping